# How to set pythonpath (python2.6) for tkinter on Ubuntu 9.04 (to use nltk)?

Tags: python, tkinter, nltk, pythonpath

I'd like to use the nltk toolkit on my machine which runs Ubuntu 9.04. I installed python 2.6.4 and several additional packages (numpy, scipy, matplotlib and of course nltk). I can import nltk, but calling a few methods gives various error masseges, all contain "please install Tkinter library".
Googling around I discovered from http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter that I should set my pythonpath environment variable. However I couldn't find out how to do this after searching for hours.

Comment: I find it interesting that calling methods gives you various massages. Now that's a feature!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you forgot to install the appropriate TkInter when you installed Python 2.6.4. Install it from the same source.

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter is usually included with the python standard libraries but Ubuntu left it out of the regular python package.  You just need to install the **python-tk** package.

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```